# Tableau: sum of null rows

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to create a calculated field that sums rows of data where two columns are both missing data. I'm trying this:

```
SUM( INT( ISNULL( [Column1] ) AND ISNULL( [Column2] ) ) )
```

However, this gives me very odd results. In one example, I'm getting a result of 882 with the code above where there are a total of 35 rows, where only 10 rows are missing values. I've tried many variations, I'm always getting way too high numbers. The columns in question contains strings, so ZN() won't work. Changing aliases don't seem to make any difference.

What (probably simple) thing am I missing?

Edit: After comments - removing the sum in the CF and then re-adding it as an aggregation makes no difference. Yes, it is a combination of two database tables. The following is the table view without the sum in the CF:
[image]

Red is column 2 and pink is column 1. So the CF definitely shows something different for the blank rows, but I can't figure out why it ends up with 99 and 45 (and why sometimes one and sometimes the other). Ideally, I should be getting just 1s and 0s. Green are unique IDs.

Comment: Your formula looks correct. Any chance you can mock up some sample raw data and also show what result you get using that sample data?

Comment: Assuming this field as CF, try removing sum from the calculated portion and try using it as measure sum instead i.e. sum(CF)

Comment: If you take the SUM() out of the calculated field definition as @AnilGoyal suggests, then you view the underlying data to check the calculation’s behavior at the individual data row level - which can be instructive

Comment: Are you using joins on multiple tables?

Comment: @AlexBlakemore updated post after your comment

Comment: Its hard to tell for sure without a complete example, but I suspect @AnilGoyal is on to something when asking about joins. If you are joining tables that have a one-to-many relationship, you necessarily generate duplicate data and need to design your calculations accordingly.

Comment: Try viewing the underlying data and seeing whether you see duplicate records. If you want a more helpful response, post some sample data showing the result you expect and  the result you get instead. There is only so much anyone can tell you based on a screen shot — you don’t need to post real data, simplify and sanitize it just to illustrate the problem

Comment: I totally agree with @Alex .  Without a complete example of data structure of both tables it is very hard to tell.  By joins i meant the same point i.e. probably one to many relationship may have caused this problem.  Moreover tableau has feature to use multiple data sources without join.  In such cases rows may multiply if view generated consists of columns from both data sources aggegated on some field.  The view presented by pkg isn't of any help in absence of data structure.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I can't reproduce the data unfortunately, it's just too much work (and/or I'm not good enough with Tableau). But I tried removing all joins in the Data Source tab, which instantly fixed the problem. So @AnilGoyal's hunch was right. This breaks some other functionality, but now I know where to look. Thanks again, sorry if this was frustrating to try to help with.